Passing a single char as pointer if it isn't changed anyway
I have found this pattern and I don't know if it's something strange happening or some kind of idiom.
In C, for an M3 MCU (maybe it's an ARM specific optimization technique?) I sometime see signatures like
static bool lcdWriteByte(uint8_t rsRwBits, uint8_t * data) 

where data is indeed a single byte and it's only used as
lcdCommandBuffer[2] = (*data);

it really doesn't make sense to me except if for some reason the ARM THUMBv2 is actually faster/smaller/more efficient at loading a (constant) address than a byte from a variable.
From a programming logic point of view that should be an uint8_t data and the assignment a simple byte copy.
Ever seen anything like this?

That doesn't appear very sensible indeed, if data only ever points at a single byte. Perhaps the rationale is that you have all data for the LCD in a big array and update it by iterating through it byte by byte. Still a bit strange.

It might be that the function is written to match an API specified somewhere and that API requires the pointer (because some functions do use it as an array — for example, the bool lcdWriteString(uint8_t rsRwBits, uint8_t *data) function might use more than the single byte.

It could be to make it symmetrical with a getter function defined as bool lcdReadByte(uint8_t rsRwBits, uint8_t * data) But I agree it is horrible.

It's not only there, it's found even in other functions. And it's a write only LCD by the way. Maybe it was some strange theory of that author

@LorenzoMarcantonio: "if it isn't changed anyway" --> This is not supported by the function signature lcdWriteByte(uint8_t rsRwBits, uint8_t * data) as a well written function that does not change *data would be lcdWriteByte(uint8_t rsRwBits, const uint8_t * data). Post the code of function lcdWriteByte() so we can see its true functionality.

that was the reason I asked. it isn't changed and it isn't either useful to use it as a pointer. The only use it does with it is the shown assignment and that buffer is simply passed to the i2c routine. There is no reason to use a pointer but I've seen the pattern in many other functions (this is the simplest one). 6k lines without comments to maintain are not fun
